# Multiple Orders in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a shopify storefront where I sell to the public. I have a list of customers I would like to send a product to as a gift.

I have about 110 customers names, address, phone and shirt size. All the billing info will be mine.

Is there a way for me to import a csv or some file so I don't have to manually do 110 different orders?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on another SE site, that isnt on the Closing list. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to import the orders using standard Shopify functionality. You would need to use an app, create your own script or do that manually.